# If my Remote Desktop Connection Broker server goes down, can users still access my two Terminal Servers?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services

I would like to setup the Remote Desktop Connection Broker to allow better load balancing of the two terminal servers we have as well as allowing the user to re-establish to the correct server if they get disconnected.

My worry is, if I set this up and the server this service is running goes down, does the terminal server stop accepting connections or will they just lose the benefit of having RDCB turned on?  I don't want to add another point of failure in this equation unless I have to.

Comment: The title of this question does not sound right when read out loud. You may want to edit it using the edit link.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what I was thinking when I posted it.  Title edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you doing load balancing between the two?  If you are using a simple round-robin DNS distribution then if the connection broker goes down (provided that it is only providing that single role), then the terminal servers should continue to operate.  People will still be able to connect to the servers, and load will continue to be split between the servers.

The load between the servers can and will become somewhat unbalanced.  But If you leave enough head-room on your servers, this probably won't be that big of an issue.

If a person loses their connection, gets disconnected, and attempts to reconnect, they may be connected to a different server.  In that case, they would have two open sessions.  They would possibly lose some data, particularly if they tried to work on a file that was already open in the other session.

Comment: We will be using round robin to split the load between the two servers.  This is exactly the information I needed.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

While I don't use the Session Broker, it seems to me that if the Session Broker is the point of entry to your TS "farm" (as it probably should be) then if the Session Broker server is down nobody will be able to connect to the TS servers in the "farm".

Can you give us some specifics regarding your setup?

Comment: Connections are not made through the session broker, unless you also have NLB or something else running on the same system as the session broker.  The session broker is only consulted when a RDP connection is being established.